# Refresh View on table update in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to update/refresh my view as soon as items are inserted in my DB table. Summaries is my controller view which need to refreshed upon table update in my Lists controller. Below is the code in lists controller.

```
if not_valid.blank?
      lists.map(&:save)
      @lists = lists
      redirect_to :controller => "summaries", :action => :index
```

The server log displays that it has redirected to this, but nothing happens on my page.

```
Redirected to http://192.168.1.6:3000/summaries/index
```

I had to refresh manually to view updated contents. After manual refresh the updated results are displayed. Do I need to use observer pattern in this scenario or this can be achieved otherwise. I researched a lot but couldn't find a solution as in how to implement this. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: The lists is not loaded properly. Try load lists as @lists = List.all.

Comment: Thanks. But the lists is being loaded correctly as I can see values in DB. So I don't think that is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use javascript in some way or another. Read up on how to use Rails with Ajax/jQuery.

In general. your controller needs to respond to javascript.

This is so that when you click a button to add a new entry into your table, it will trigger the `summaries#index` action, which will then call a partial to execute the javascript which would (presumably) append the new entry into the DOM.

The short story is there's probably nothing wrong with the code, but Rails does not 'magically' update your views when you insert new data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for info. Just a small query. In my view I am not updating anything. Every time on refresh the DB table is read and the page contents are populated a fresh. All this is done in my index method of summaries view. So basically I just want to execute index method on new data insertion and rest it will handle. For this   implementation, do I need to have the things suggested. Also I just read that 'Pusher' or something similar can be used. This is my first app of this kind so in dilemma as in what would fit best.

Comment: Using Pusher doesn't free you from having to do some Javascript. Check this out to get an idea: http://stjhimy.com/posts/07-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript. It is slightly old, but you will get the general idea.